# Python datetime.strftime and datetime.strptime

Tags: python, datetime, strptime

I was reading a chapter on datetime from 'Effective Python' and stumbled upon this strange behavior of datetime.strptime: it raises a ValueError on the very string formatted with datetime.strftime using the same format. if I remove the timezone component then it parses just fine.

Anyone has an explanation? Thanks in advance!

code here:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

TIME_FORMAT = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z'

pacific = pytz.timezone('US/Pacific')
time = datetime.now().astimezone(pacific)
time_str = time.strftime(TIME_FORMAT) # >>> '2018-02-15 05:20:50 PST'

# next line: ValueError: time data '2018-02-15 05:30:34 PST' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z'
time_parsed = datetime.strptime(time_str, TIME_FORMAT)
```

Comment: Seems like strptime doesn't accept the timezone (%Z) bit.

Comment: There is an old discussion about this problem: https://bugs.python.org/issue22377

Comment: change `%Z` to `%z` and it'll work.

Comment: Which version of Python?  This changed in 3.2.

Comment: @Marii Thanks, that was it.